# Ember App Kit: Cannot find viewClass for template outlet

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-app-kit

I've got my `application.hbs` template where I declare several `{{outlet}}`s (named & unnamed) and one with specified `viewClass` property:

**application.hbs**:

```
{{outlet 'modal'}}
{{outlet 'notification'}}
<h1>EAK Application</h1>
{{#view 'application/content'}}
  {{!some HTML markup, etc. }}

  {{outlet viewClass='application/content-container'}}
{{/view}}
```

and my view files are placed under

```
app/views/application/content.js
app/views/application/content-container.js
```

But Ember App Kit cannot find the `content-container` view!

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find view at path
>   'views/application/content-container'

Am I doing something wrong?

### Edit

---

Meanwhile I do the simple workaround and call it like

```
{{#view 'application/content-container'}}
  {{outlet}}
{{/view}}
```

but this gives my an extra `<div>` layer and is "less elegant" imho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Ember API reference (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet) says the property on the outlet should be `view` not `viewClass`:

```
{{#view 'application/content'}}
  {{!some HTML markup, etc. }}

  {{outlet view='application/content-container'}}
{{/view}}
```

Without a full understanding of the app your building, I can't make a specific recommendation, but if you want to take advantage of the deep linking URLs, you should use routes when possible to assign templates/views to outlets.

For example your IndexRoute will expect an `IndexTemplate` and an `IndexView` (or will create one behind the scenes). In the Ember App Kit they would be located in `app/views/index.js` and `app/templates/index.hbs`. Check out the `Rendering a Template` guide on Ember's site: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Alternatively you could also use the view helper like:

`{{view 'my-view'}}`

The is different than the normal Ember [view helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/) where the view helper expects the actual class. In the Ember App Kit, it's the path to the file based on the file name and path of the view from the `app/views` root.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer - I'm familiar with the template rendering and the overall codestructure. this is/was working code in an Ember.js application but now, as I'm migrating this application to use Ember App Kit it fails. I'm using the `viewClass` within the `{{outlet}}` so that I don't generate another unused/needless `<div>` layer within my HTML markup :)

Comment: Again I'm not familiar with viewClass as an available attribute. It doesn't come up really in any google searches either. Nested in the EmberJS API docs is a reference to the 'view' attribute, but not viewClass: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet. I'm not sure where the extra div comes in either. Can you update your answer to include the contents of the hbs templates or maybe create jsbin working example.

Comment: ahhhh @AaronStorck ... I was so blind to oversee the `view` attribute you mentioned - seems like my `viewClass` attribute is some ancestor from previous versions (or something the like...). Works with `view` like expected, thanks! would you consider to mention this "solution" in your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to more accurately provide the answer to your question.